# Get string from C# class returned to Typescript to use in Chart-js

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, typescript

My background has been in TSQL and not webpages, but here I am, trying to use chart.js to graph sales data by day.
Chart.js is working fine and I can define an array of data in the typescript file and have it chart that just fine.

But the problem is when I try to bring data in from the server.

Environment : Visual Studio 2017
Languages :   Typescript and C#

I have a Controller with a method that returns the data to graph.

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult getSalesByDayData(string raffleCode)
        {
            int[] testdata = { 20, 30, 40, 50 };
            string[] testnames = {"1/11","2/11","3/11","4/11"}
            MyChartData _chartData = new MyChartData();
            _chartData.chartData = testdata;
            _chartData.chartLabels = testnames;
            return new ObjectResult(_chartData);
        }

        /* Chart Data Classes */
    public class MyChartData
        {
            public string[] chartLabels { get; set; }
            public int[] chartData { get; set; }

        }
```

This is registered in raffle.service.ts as

```
 getByDayGraph(raffleCode: string) {

        return this.http.get('api/Raffle/getSalesByDayData', { params: { raffleCode: raffleCode } })
            .map(response => response.json() as byDayChartData[])
            .toPromise();
    }
```

And in byDayChartData.type.ts

```
export class byDayChartData 
{
    public chartLabels: string[];
    public chartData: number[];

}
```

Then when I use it in detail.component.ts

```
this.raffleService.getByDayGraph(this.raffleCode)
        .then(graphData => {
            this.datain = graphData;
        });

// This doesn't work
this.barChartData = [{ data: this.datain[0].chartData, label: 'Heading' }]; 

 // this however, works fine
   this.barChartData = [{ data: [20,30,50,60], label: 'Chart Heading' }];
```

I reason that it is not in the correct format to be used.  So the question then is , what is that format and how do I change the data into it.

Thanks for reading all that, I hope someone can help.

Comment: The function you define in `.then` doesn’t get called til the data retrieval is complete, and by that time the rest of your code (outside of `.then`) has already executed.  Try putting your “this doesnt work”  code inside the function defined in `.then`.

Comment: Thanks for the repy James this.raffleService.getByDayGraph(this.raffleCode)
   .then(graphData => {
  //  this.datain = graphData[0].chartData;
    this.barChartData = [{ data: graphData[0].chartData, label: 'HEADING HERE' }];
   });
But there was no change.